# Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: film is not associated to film

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, associations, postman

I am attempting to have a database POST and update through postman but it's leading to an Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError

This has been attempted and successful using an actor.js from the database but currently unsuccessful with the film database

My assocation.js:

```
module.exports = function(models) {
    models.actor.belongsToMany(models.film, 
        { 
            through: models.film_actor,
            foreignKey: 'actor_id'
        });
    models.film.belongsToMany(models.actor,
        {
            through: models.film_actor,
            foreignKey: 'film_id'
        });
}
```

models film.js:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('film', {
    film_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(5).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    release_year: {
      type: "YEAR(4)",
      allowNull: true
    },
    language_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(3).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'language',
        key: 'language_id'
      }
    },
    original_language_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(3).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'language',
        key: 'language_id'
      }
    },
    rental_duration: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(3).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '3'
    },
    rental_rate: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '4.99'
    },
    length: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(5).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true
    },
    replacement_cost: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '19.99'
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17'),
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: 'G'
    },
    special_features: {
      type: "SET('TRAILERS','COMMENTARIES','DELETED SCENES','BEHIND THE SCENES')",
      allowNull: true
    },
    last_update: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'film'
  });
};
```

routes films.js:

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var models = require('../models/')

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  models.find
    .findAll({ 
      attributes: ['film_id','title','description', 'release_year']    
    })
    .then(filmsFound => {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(JSON.stringify(filmsFound));
    });
});
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  models.film
    .findByPk(parseInt(req.params.id), { 
      include: [{ model: models.film }]
    })
    .then(filmsFound => {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(JSON.stringify(filmsFound));
    })
});
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  models.actor.findOrCreate({
    where: { 
      title: req.body.title
    }
  })
  .spread(function(result, created) {
    if (created) {
      res.redirect('/films/' + result.film_id);
    } else {
      res.status(400);
      res.send('Film already exists');
    }
  })
});
router.put("/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  let filmId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  models.film
    .update(req.body, { where: { film_id: filmId } })
    .then(result => res.redirect('/films/' + filmId))
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400);
      res.send("There was a problem updating the film.  Please check the film information.");
    });
});
router.delete("/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  let filmId = parseInt(req.params.id);
  models.film
    .destroy({
      where: { film_id: filmId }
    })
    .then(result => res.redirect('/films'))
    .catch(err => { 
      res.status(400); 
      res.send("There was a problem deleting the film. Please make sure you are specifying the correct id."); 
    }
);
});

  module.exports = router;
```

views app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var actorsRouter = require ('./routes/actors');
var filmsRouter = require('./routes/films');
var models = require('./models');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/actors', actorsRouter);
app.use('/films', filmsRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

models.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
  console.log("DB Sync'd up")
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out posting the answer for whoever is stuck on the similar issue.Had to reorganize my GET requests in the routes film.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  models.film
    .findAll({ 
      attributes: ['film_id', 'title', 'description', 'rental_rate', 'rating'],     
    })
    .then(filmsFound => {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(JSON.stringify(filmsFound));
    });
});
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  models.film
    .findByPk(parseInt(req.params.id), { 
    })
    .then(filmsFound => {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(JSON.stringify(filmsFound));
    })
});
```